# Saving off raw with Camera2 on a camera with rowstride > width

Tags: android, android-camera2

What I have developed thus far is the capability to write out various devices raw information using the standard `DngCreator` scheme as per below.

On one device that I am encountering however (HTC 10) the `Image` class contains planar information whose row stride is larger than the width.  I so far have an understanding that this can happen with images, but I can't find out how to correct for it with the SDK available to us.

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(cameraImageF.getRawBytes());
byteBuffer.rewind();
dngCreator.writeByteBuffer(new FileOutputStream(rawLoggerFileF),
                new Size(cameraImageF.getRawImageSize().getWidth(), cameraImageF.getRawImageSize().getHeight()),
                byteBuffer, 0);
```

I have held onto the bytes from the original `Image` class and do some substantial calculations in between when I received them and when they were taken (this is the point of the application).  So, I need to let go of the `Image` so that I can keep getting additional frames from the camera.

Now, this approach works fine for various devices (Samsung S7, Nexus 5, Nexus 6p, etc.).  However on the HTC 10 the stride is 16 bytes longer per row and it seems as though I have no way of letting the `DngCreator` know that.

Underneath in the source code, the writeBuffer defaults to an internal `rowStride = width * pixelStride`.  I do not have the capability to send in a different stride for a parameter.  The rowStride does not equal the defaults.

The `dngCreator.saveImage(Outputstream, Image)` uses the internal Image's stride when it writes out to a buffer.  However, I can't hold on to an `Image` class on the camera because it needs to be released and it is not a cloneable object.

I am a bit lost and trying to understand how to write out a valid .dng for a photograph that has rowStride > width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to remove the extra bytes manually - that is, copy the raw image to a new ByteBuffer, and remove the extra bytes at the end of each row. So something like:

```
byte[] rawBytes = cameraImageF.getRawBytes();
ByteBuffer dst = ByteBuffer.allocate(cameraImageF.getRawImageSize().getWidth() * cameraImageF.getRawImageSize().getHeight() * 2);
for (int row = 0; row < cameraImageF.getRawImageSize().getHeight(); row++) {
   dst.put(rawBytes, 
       row * cameraImageF.getRawImageRowStride(), 
       cameraImageF.getRawImageSize().getWidth() * 2);
}
dst.rewind();
dngCreator.writeByteBuffer(new FileOutputStream(rawLoggerFileF),
            new Size(cameraImageF.getRawImageSize().getWidth(),   
                  cameraImageF.getRawImageSize().getHeight()),
            dst, 0);
```

That's of course not lovely for performance, but since DngCreator won't let you specify a row stride with the ByteBuffer interface, it's your only option.

Is there a reason you can't just increase your RAW ImageReader's maxCount to a higher one, so that you can hold on to the Image until you're done processing it?

Comment: Thanks Eddy, I might have to go this route I think.  Perhaps I did not understand the `maxCount` parameter and what its purpose was for though.  I will research back into that and possible change my container to maintain the `Image` class if that is how it is meant to function.

Comment: ImageReader's maxCount argument defines how many Images you can hold on to at the same time before you have to release one back to the system.  ImageReader is a circular buffer underneath; the more Image you hold, the larger the memory consumption gets, and if you don't release Images back fast enough the camera won't have anywhere to put the next capture's image data (and will stall).  So you still have to release Images at the same rate as you capture images, but if you increase maxCount, you can hold each one longer in a processing pipeline.